# Extracting meta tags attribute using wget

Tags: html, meta-tags

I have a file having some URLs per line. I need to extract the "keywords" present in the tags i.e. if there is meta tag for "keywords" then i want to get "content" value for it. Example: if the web-page has this meta-tag then for that URL i want "wikipedia,encyclopedia" to be extracted.

One approach is to download the web-page using "wget" and then parse it using some standard HTML parser.

I was wondering is there any better way to do this without downloading the entire web-page.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is the simplest solution to implement.

If you worried about the network traffic generated you could write a small program that only reads the header. As soon as you read the `<body..>` tag you can finish downloading.

**Update**: You have to set a very small receive buffer for you socket otherwise the kernel will probably still download the whole page. Verify your solution with `tcpdump`.

Comment: but how do I process the web-page while it is still downloading by wget() ??

Comment: The simple answer is you don't. You can do `wget -O -` and process `stdin` but then you have to set up the kernel receive buffer for all sockets with `sysctl` which is certainly NOT a good idea. You have to write this in C++ or python or anything that lets you manipulate sockets... If this sounds too complex for you just download the whole page.